# Find heigh of opened panel of accordion with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to calculate the height of an opened panel of an accordion and use it as variable.

As soon as I load the page the panel is closed so it has a smaller height than the panel when opened. I would like to find the height after I click the panel title and it's completly opened.

How could I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to get an elements height with jQuery

```
$("#elementId").height();
```

Or

```
$("#elementId").css("height");
```

The difference between .css( "height" ) and .height() is that the latter returns a unit-less pixel value (for example, 400) while the former returns a value with units intact (for example, 400px). The .height() method is recommended when an element's height needs to be used in a mathematical calculation.

[Check jQuery docs on height here](http://api.jquery.com/height/)

---

Then to know the height of your panel after it has opened, you will need to **bind an event listener** to the desired accordion event.

Since you are using jQuery, you can use the `.on` function to bind to an event:

```
$("#elementId").on( "eventName", function() {
   console.log($(this).height());
});
```

Below is the documentation on the exact events you would need to bind to if you are using a bootstrap accordion or a jQuery UI accordion (*I could be more specific with a code example if I knew what kind of accordion you were using*)

[Bootstraps collapse accordion Events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-events)

[jQuery UI accordion Events](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#events)

Comment: Thanks for reply JustSomeDude but maybe I did not explayned correctly. I need to find the height of the panel of my accordion after I click on the panel title and it expands vertically.

Comment: @Francesco sorry I missed that in your question. I will update my answer to give you more information, but without knowing exactly what type of accordion you are using, then I cannot give you an exact code example. If you let me know, I can be more helpful.

Comment: Thanks for reply again! I use Bootstrap Accordion. I'll try to fit what you suggested to my needs. Thanks so much!